# Videos not loading on Mobile or Tablet Nextjs

Tags: html, css, reactjs, next.js

so i have a problem with the video's working and playing fine when visiting the website from a desktop. But when using a tablet or a mobile device the video just shows white, no error, no warning just white and nothing. I have tried multiple things changed it from mp4 to webm, added playsInline as css property but to no avail. Could anyone help me, I am clueless. I added the code below. Has anyone had this problem before?

I am using NextJs 14 with the App router.

```
          <video
              className="absolute h-full w-full object-cover"
              src="/hero-video.webm"
              type="video/webm"
              preload="auto"
              autoPlay
              muted
              loop
              playsInline
            ></video>
```

Comment: Have you tried embedding the source inside the video tag ?
<video controls width="250">
  <source src="/media/cc0-videos/flower.webm" type="video/webm" />
like this